# Get all DLLImports from an Assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

How to enum all DLLImports from an Assembly using reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through every method in every class, and check whether `GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DllImportAttribute))` returns anything.

Answer (score 3):

```
assembly.GetTypes()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods(flags))
        .Where(m => Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(m, typeof(DllImportAttribute)) != null);
```